# Bootstrap Collapse not automatically collapsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I just inserted a Bootstrap collapse into my payment view in Laravel. The Bootstrap collapses when I click on it, But I want it to be collapsed automatically.

I know I have to set this: `aria-expanded="false"`

But its still not working. Maybe because it has its own id like this?

`href="#collapse{{ $charity->id }}"`

Here is my full panel snippet:

```
@foreach($charities as $charity)

    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse{{ $charity->id }}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
                                <img class="media-object" src="{{ $charity->photo }}" width="75px" height="65px" alt="{{ $charity->name }}">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-10 col-md-10">
                                {{ $charity->name }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse{{ $charity->id }}" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    {{ $charity->description }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

@endforeach
```

Comment: try removing the collapse class from `id="collapse{{ $charity->id }}"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the first panel closed on page load, remove the `.in` class from it.

From this -->   `<div id="collapse{{ $charity->id }}" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">`

To this --> `<div id="collapse{{ $charity->id }}" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">`

> The collapse plugin utilizes a few classes to handle the heavy
>   lifting:
>
> 1. .collapse hides the content
> 2. .collapse.in shows the content
> 3. .collapsing is added when the transition starts, and removed when it finishes

See [Collapse Usage](https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-usage) in the Docs.

**Example:**

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">

    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
              <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" width="75px" height="65px" alt="alt">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-10 col-md-10">
              NAME
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
        DESC
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```